# Java version on 32 bit and 64 bit os

Tags: java, release

I'm doing a task of getting the latest java version from web site http://java.sun.com/update/1.7.0/map-m-1.7.0.xml and then compare with the java installed in the local machine. If the local java version is not the latest, then alert user.

In Windows 64 bit machine users can install both 32 bit java and 64 bit java, so I have to get all java versions from registry and compare the local java versions with the latest java version.

My question is: Every time when a new version of java is released, will they release new version for both 32 bit and 64 bit at the same time? And for both 32 bit and 64 bit version, will the version number be the same?

If the 32 bit and 64 bit version maybe not released at the same time, then the way to get the latest java version from http://java.sun.com/update/1.7.0/map-m-1.7.0.xml maybe not accurate since I have to distinguish the version of 32 bit and 64 bit. Does anyone have any idea of getting latest java version(full version) for both 32 bit and 64 bit os?

Comment: probably you should subscribe some newsletter or RSS from Oracle website. then after they release new version, you will receive notification:)

Comment: Why are you using a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS at all?

Answer (score 1):

> Every time when a new version of java is released, will they release new version for both 32 bit and 64 bit at the same time?

No.  There have been cases where the 32 bit version appeared first.  I expect there will come a time when the 64 bit version arrives first.